# mongodb dict to csv in python, UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, csv

At the end of processing some data using pymongo, I have a list `email_list[]`.  when I run:

```
for z in range (0,5):
    print email_list[z]
```

I get:

```
{u'_id': ObjectId('52ab110e763f4aec448b670a'), u'email': u'first.last@email.com'}
{u'_id': ObjectId('52cc62bc763f4aec418b46f8'), u'email': u'test.smith@gmail.com'}
{u'_id': ObjectId('52b4b2a0763f4a61198b4760'), u'email': u'jim.doe@hotmail.com'}
{u'_id': ObjectId('52bae9b3763f4a9c4b8b4575'), u'email': u'foo@bar.com'}
{u'_id': ObjectId('52c2e3e6763f4a572d8b45e3'), u'email': u'bill@gmail.com'}
```

I'm trying to write the list to a csv.  I have:

```
my_dict = email_list[0]

with open('new_file.csv','wb') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,my_dict.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(my_dict)
    for row in email_list:
        w.writerow(row)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mongodb_script_1.py", line 74, in <module>
w.writerow(row)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 148, in writerow
return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 22: ordinal not in range(128)
```

However, the file `new_file.csv` seems to have the id's and emails.

What's going on?

Comment: did u tried import unicodecsv instead of csv.

Comment: Sorry, don't know what that means.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import unicodecsv as csv
with open('new_file.csv','w') as f:
w = csv.DictWriter(f,my_dict[0].keys())
w.writeheader()
for row in t:
    del row['_id']
    w.writerow(row)
```

You cannot insert '_id' in csv as it is an object of mongodb delete it before inserting

Comment: sudo pip install unicodecsv

if pip is not installed 
try: sudo apt-get install python-pip

Comment: Those commands don't work.  I found the file here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv - I downloaded the file.  how do I install it?

Comment: OK. Got everything installed, ran your code and got: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mongodb_script_1.py", line 80, in <module>
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,my_dict[0].keys())
KeyError: 0
`

Comment: if mydict = email_list then use mydict[0].keys() or if u are using mydict = email_list[0] then use mydict.keys()